# Regex Issues (In C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following patterns:

```
private static Regex rgxDefinitionDoMatch = new Regex(@"d:(?<value>(?:(?!c:|d:|p:).)+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex rgxDefinitionDontMatch = new Regex(@"\!d:(?<value>(?:(?!c:|d:|p:).)+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex rgxDefinitionExactDoMatch = new Regex(@"d:(?<value>\""(?:(?!c:|d:|p:).)+)\""", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static Regex rgxDefinitionExactDontMatch = new Regex(@"\!d:(?<value>\""(?:(?!c:|d:|p:).)+)\""", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Here is an example string to match:

```
c:matchThis !c:dontMatchThis p:matchThis !p:dontMatchThis d:def !d:defDont d:"def" !d:"defDont"
```

Now here are some issues:

1. When I use rgxDefinitionDontMatch, I get both `!d:defDont` and `d:"defDont"`
2. When I use rgxDefinitionDoMatch it is even worse... I get `!d:defDont`, `d:"defDont"`,
   `!d:def` and `d:"def"`.

For number 2, I have tried different combinations to ignore the exclamation mark on the front of rgxDefinitionDoMatch `^(?!\!)` for example, but it then just doesn't match anything. I'm not sure what to do.

I will also need a way of ignoring quotes for both problems 1. and 2.

Can anyone help? I've been trying for some time now.

Comment: [^\!]d:(?<value>(?:(?! c:| d:| p:|\ !).)+)   - this seems to do the trick for ignoring the exclamations, but only when the value is nto at the beginning of the text I am checking. If I have  d:test   at the beginning of a text, it does not match...it only matches if it is somewhere else other than the start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Regex[] rgxs = { 
  new Regex(@"(?<!\S)d:(?:""(?<value>[^""]+)""|(?<value>\S+))"),
  new Regex(@"(?<!\S)!d:(?:""(?<value>[^""]+)""|(?<value>\S+))")
};

string input = @"c:matchThis !c:dontMatchThis p:matchThis !p:dontMatchThis d:def !d:defDont d:""def"" !d:""defDont""";

foreach (Regex r in rgxs)
{
  Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
  foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
  {
    foreach (String name in r.GetGroupNames())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0,-6} => {1}", name, m.Groups[name].Value);
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
(?<!\S)d:(?:"(?<value>[^"]+)"|(?<value>\S+))
0      => d:def
value  => def
0      => d:"def"
value  => def

(?<!\S)!d:(?:"(?<value>[^"]+)"|(?<value>\S+))
0      => !d:defDont
value  => defDont
0      => !d:"defDont"
value  => defDont
```

As I was trying to figure out what you were asking, I finally decided the simplest course was to post my code and get your feedback.  I'll try to refine it as needed, and (of course) explain it. :D

---

EDIT: Here's the separate regexes you asked for in the comments:

```
Regex[] rgxs = { 
  new Regex(@"(?<!\S)d:(?<value>\S+)"),
  new Regex(@"(?<!\S)!d:(?<value>\S+)"),
  new Regex(@"(?<!\S)d:""(?<value>[^""]+)"""),
  new Regex(@"(?<!\S)!d:""(?<value>[^""]+)""")
};
```

Combining them the way I did, it doesn't matter if the "value" part is quoted or not, it's still captured--without the quotes, if they're present.  (I thought that's what you meant by "ignoring quotes".)  What's interesting about the combined form is how I used the same group name twice in the same regex-- something few regex flavors support.

`(?<!\S)`, a negative lookbehind for a non-whitespace character, solves the question you posed in your comment: it insures that every match starts either at the beginning of the string or after a whitespace character.  Similarly, the `\S+` insures that the match continues *ends* at the end of the string or before the next whitespace character.

`"[^"]+"`, obviously, matches anything enclosed in quotes, except other quotes.  It permits the value to contain whitespace, which I presumed was the reason for the separate regexes.  But I mainly wanted to point out that you didn't need to use backslashes to escape the quotes.  In a C# verbatim string, it's the extra quote that does the escaping: `@"""[^""]+"""`.

Comment: That's excellent! Now, all I need is to split those down to 4 regexes: 2 of them to match quotes and 2 without quotes: 1. Match Quotes + Exclamation, 2: Match Quotes Without Exclamation, 3: Match No Quotes + Exclamation and 4. Match No Quotes and No Exclamation. Can you do it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Alan. I do have one more question, but I'll give mark this as answer anyway because you've helped so much already. The only thing is I do HAVE to determine which ones have quotes and which don't. The bottom 2 regexes in your EDIT above work pefectly for matching only the quoted strings, but the top 2 give quoted and non-quoted. I need it to return only the non-quoted. Would this be easy? Thanks again for the help.  :-)

Comment: Ah, the following seems to do the trick:

(?<!\S)!d:(?!\")(?<value>\S+)

I haven't seen anythign wrong yet... do you perceive any issues with this?

Comment: `(?!")(?<value>\S+)` looks good to me.  My first impulse on reading your comment was `(?<value>[^\s"]+)`, but that assumes you don't want to allow quotes *anywhere* in the value.  If you just want to make sure it doesn't *start* with a quote, your way is better.